# Is the any way to see PostScript name of font in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, fonts

I need to know the PostScript name of the .ttf font. I know that you can see that using MacOS' Font Book. But is there is a way to see that in Linux? Maybe some analogical utils that can display the PostScript name of the font?

Comment: Example `$ fc-scan /usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf | grep postscriptname` ..... The reply is `postscriptname: "BitstreamVeraSans-Roman"(s)`

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using Linux utilities. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thank you. Please, create an answer so that i can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to know the PostScript name of the .ttf font.

The "Linux gnu" command is `$ fc-scan [TTF-font]`, and one of the last lines will show `postscriptname: "name"`

Example commands, and example reply

```
$ fc-scan /usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf

$ fc-scan /usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf | grep postscriptname
          postscriptname: "BitstreamVeraSans-Roman"(s)
```